# Double PostBack inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a problem with ASP.NET firing a button click twice. The button is inside an UpdatePanel, but when I click it I get two postbacks, then two button clicks, then two calls to my DAL (in that order). I've never encountered this before, and changing AutoEventWireup to false had no effect. The only workaround I can think of would be to hide the functionality in a web service and handle the complications with jQuery, which I'd rather not do for a small project.

The firebug dumps are below (these both happen from one click).
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Put the following script on the page after the ScriptManager.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var postbackControl = null; 
var parm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
parm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler); 
parm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler); 

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) 
{ 
 postbackControl = args.get_postBackElement(); 
 postbackControl.disabled = true; 
} 
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) 
{ 
postbackControl.disabled = false; 
postbackControl = null; 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you've hooked jQuery `click()` to the button, which is also implicitly inline hooked to onchange by ASP.NET?

[jQuery.change + inline onchange fn() causes fn to execute twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846833/jquery-change-inline-onchange-fn-causes-fn-to-execute-twice)

Or did you check whether you might have hooked the server-side handler twice, both declaratively in markup and imperatively in the code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, this seems to be caused by a dodgy ControlAdapter for buttons which adds a span inside the button tag to make sliding doors work.

Comment: This is really annoying, I can't see anything in the adapter source which would case this: http://pastebin.com/K9yxcFzE

Answer (score 0):

> writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "button");

make no sense but works

Comment: could use a little more explanation for that one line of code

Answer (score 0):

If using a `<button>` with OnServerClick and Runat="server", within the aspnet form, the onclick event will contain the __doPostback call. you need to append a 'return false;' to the onclick so the button doesn't trigger a form submit (postback).

```
    <button ID="btnID" runat="server" OnServerClick="btnID_Click" onclick="doJavascript();">GO</button>

<script>
    $("#btnID").attr('onclick', $("#btnID").attr('onclick')+";return false;")
</script>
```